# How to get statup home screen like Linked_in mobile app?

Tags: android, slider, android-viewpager

I tried in so many ways to get start up screen while opening the app but unable to get as like Linked-in android mobile app home screen.Here i need to show one part of big image in first slide then after 2 seconds it automatically moves right to left and shows second part that image with text and click-able button. How to achieve it please help me.

Here is the linked in mobile app link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.linkedin.android&hl=en

> I tried this but not getting as exactly i want

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);
        //display the logo during 2 seconds,
        new CountDownTimer(2*1000,1000){
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){} 

            @Override
            public void onFinish(){
                   //set the new Content of your activity
                   YourActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.second);
            }
       }.start();
    }
```

Comment: i think you want to create splash screen m i right?

Comment: @shylendra If you found the solution please let me know .. I too wanted to develop same kind of splash screen

Answer (score 0):

```
    As per my understanding you require splash screen ..

    Splash.java
    ---------------

    public class Splash extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

            Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        int logoTimer = 0;
                        while (logoTimer < 3000) {
                            sleep(100);
                            logoTimer = logoTimer + 100;
                        }

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, NewClassToOpen.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            };
            logoTimer.start();
        }

    }

    activity_splash.xml
    -------------------


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/splash"
         >

    </LinearLayout>

    @drawable/splash --- > Place image to drawable folders with name "splash / or as you need"

This is for left to right animation:

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="700"/>
</set>

This is for right to left animation:

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
     android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="700" />
</set>

    Enjoy .. Cheers !
```

Comment: Thank you for giving quick answer i'll try n let you know.

Comment: Actually this is not my requirement. I want to show slide show of one single image two times just like Liked-in app.

Comment: For that you need to animate Splash screen. For now you can consult http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/ ... also check my edit for "Left to Right " and " Right to Left " animation code. Will get on this soon.